# What are the arguments for absolutist morality?

Tags: ethics

An absolutist ethics/morality is one that considers something immoral regardless of consequence, situation, and circumstance. Even if something has negative/positive consequences, or even if something is done under duress and out of necessity, this something is always immoral without exception

I've been told that absolutist morality is lazy. How can the absolutist position be defended?

Comment: See e.g. [Moore’s Moral Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moore-moral/)

Comment: If moral arguments play out consistently in game theory there is a argument for absolute moral positions.

Comment: I was reading about Moore the other day @MauroALLEGRANZA via Russell. doesn't Moore mean absolute morality is the claim that moral prescriptions all share in some higher order goodness, and Rusell deny that a) anything can be good with enough reality to justify statements about "goodness", and b) that there are good sentimental (i.e. ethical) reasons to suppose no such thing can exist (unelaborated in the text I, quickly, read)

Comment: See Waldron's review [What are Moral Absolutes Like?](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1906850) Part of the problem is that even authors who declare allegiance to moral absolutes in the headline quickly proceed to qualifications, distinctions and exceptions in the text when faced with concrete examples . [Doctrine of Double Effect](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/double-effect/) is a typical case. So it hard to describe what "absolute" really means.

Comment: "I've been told absolutist morality is lazy", if this counts as a valid reason to argue against any doctrine or theory, then what about there's really an absolute ultimate physical theory of everything which is dreamed of and pursued *diligently* by many contemporary physicists? Also laziness can only be claimed by moral practitioners themselves, how other people can judge and claim such internal attribute? Absolute moral objectivism doesn't necessarily mean easy, most likely extremely hard since it has to take into account every possible situations like a legal or religious code system.

Comment: @DoubleKnot I think "lazy" refers to positing a small number of one-size-fits-all-no-matter-what rules without bothering to analyze moral nuances in diverse situations, intellectually lazy. But if it is any consolation, "*naive relativism has also been criticised as being the “lazy way out” for, without critical evaluation or reflection, one could question how an individual is to facilitate comparison and enhancement of his or her moral standards*", [McDonald, Ethical relativism vs absolutism](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/09555341011056203/full/pdf). Extremes meet.

Comment: @Conifold And what if I don't believe the extreme that something is immoral regardless of the diverse situations or whatever is lazy? Now what?

Answer (score 2):

One perhaps obvious argument would be **executive efficiency**, which is essentially the cause behind using heuristics in general. A system, whether a single brain or a whole society, which has substantially limited executive capacity or otherwise which requires fast turnover, could easily benefit from using heuristics such as simple, absolute rules. The result may not be ideal or fair for special cases, but it would likely be systemically efficient.

An example statement from this position might be:

*We cannot afford to waste time on special cases.*

Comment: I don't think an absolutist would be very convinced by your argument, because absolutists, by their very nature, deny there are special cases

Answer (score 1):

> I've been told absolutist morality is lazy

In a way that makes sense.

I suppose arguments for absolutism hinge on our intuitive beliefs that some things are immoral independent of any states of affairs, as well as problems with [moral relativism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-relativism/):

> a metaethical thesis that the truth or justification of moral
> judgments is not absolute, but relative to the moral standard of some
> person or group of persons

Note that in some sense all the great meta ethical theories are absolute: even act consequentialism says that we should *always* perform the action with the best consequences. Indeed I suspect you are asking about deontology, looking for deontological proscriptions which hold dependent upon consequences. But sadly that would be nothing at all in the spirit of it, so I'd guess you should just read amore about act [consequentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/)

> The paradigm example of a Consequentialist ethics, Classical
> Utilitarianism, is also a perfect example of Absolutism: any action
> which maximizes pleasure or happiness is right and good absolutely,
> whatever else may be the case.

Absolutism v consequentialism: no contest
Don Locke
Analysis, Volume 41, Issue 2, April 1981, Pages 101–106,